# Hitting .NET Dictionary limit – what exactly?

Tags: .net, dictionary, out-of-memory, console-application, outofrangeexception

In a x64 .NET console app, I load a large lookup table into a `Dictionary<object, object>`. In this particular case both key and value are strings, but the app needs to be agnostic. The strings are 12 single-byte characters and 15-17 single-byte characters each (digits and a-z). The lookup table contains ~55 million records.

I need to load it into RAM for performance, DB won't be great.

The problem is that after loading about 49 million records I get an out of range exception from the `Dictionary`. At this time, the process has commit size of about 8 Gbyte. The server it's running on has 24 Gbyte RAM and there's plenty left. OS and app are both 64 bit.

I tried splitting into a second `Dictionary` after 30 million items, which works, so it's not a RAM limitation per se. Must be a limitation in `Dictionary`.

I'm wondering what limitation that might be. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your application 64-bit?

Comment: @specializt I think your judgment isn't accurate enough. Based on requirements keeping huge amount of data in memory can be totally reasonable thing.

Comment: @UweKeim, yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. Will edit...

Comment: @specializt You're wrong. I know exactly what I'm doing and why.

Comment: You may know "exactly what you're doing" but it still is a design flaw and programming mistake ... and a quite notorious one, actually

Comment: @specializt I do know how to use databases and do that quite a lot. But doing millions of index lookups in a relational DB is just too slow compared to doing the same in RAM in this case. At least that's my judgement. A better data structure than generic `Dictionary` could prove useful though, but requires more work.

Comment: and thats exactly where you're wrong - databases are not entirely disk-based anymore, thats a fact from the early days of IT

Comment: @specializt Alright, granted.

Comment: Maybe posting a detailed error message and a stack trace (including the parts inside the .NET Framework) would help to further narrow down on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element?view=netframework-4.7.2) states that:

> Arrays greater than 2 GB in total size are not enabled. This is the default.

Most probably you are hitting this limitation. You can override that behavior by adding this in your application configuration:

```
<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try changing the hashcode of the string. Upper and lowercase code of the string differ by 0x20. A fast way to ignore case is to either OR every char with 0x20 (for lower-case) or AND every char with ~0x20 (for upper-case) prior to hashing.

Also, C# isnt designed for processing millions, billions of records. Maybe try storing it in SqlLite and get it in batches. Sql is pretty good for dealing with millions of records.

I recently had a problem where The need was to query millions of records to find if record exists. I ended up using Bloom Filter to tell if a record doesnt exists.

Comment: I don't think any disk based solution will provide acceptable performance. At least that's my experience from similar cases in the past. That said, a relational DB might be able to get its entire content cached, but there are ad hoc run-once file conversions, so I pretty much believe the cache will have to be "reloaded" on every run. I may read up on the hash and Bloom filter suggestions. Thanks. Not marking as answer because my question was what limitation exactly I might be hitting.